# Validate a specific country Carrier operator phone number regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate a phone number for a specific carrier operator using RegEx in C#, e.g. 94773650101
94 is the country code
77 is the carrier operator it can also be 76
how do I validate this using RegEx in C#. I need a format for it.

I've tried

```
var match = Regex.Match(mobileNo, @"\d947(\d7|6)\d{7}/");
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. This is not a site which gives you code you can copy paste. Unless you have a problem in your code, nobody can help you.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, var match = Regex.Match(mobileNo, @"\d947(\d7|6)\d{7}/");

Comment: What type of validation do you need?  If it is just two characters than it is better to use the string.Substring(2,2) to get the field.  If you are trying to test the number of character in the phone number including the space then regex is appropriate.

Comment: i actually need to validate a specific pattern for a specific carrier operator, var match = Regex.Match(mobileNo, @"\d947(\d7|6)\d{7}/"); this is what i have done so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is very simple, try this: `^947[76]\d{7}$`

There is an errors in your regexp: **\d**947(**\d**7|6)\d{7}**/**

I've mark it bold. You don't need to use `\d` before `947` or `7|6`,
`\d` is any digit. 
And what for `/` at the end?

**UPD for leading zeroes:**

`^(00)?947[76]\d{7}$`

Comment: thanks a lot your answer did work for me, and one more thing how can i say there can be 2 more 00 in front of 94, sometimes it may not be too so how do i change my pattern according to that scenario.

Comment: @Isham, example?

Comment: there can be a mobile number with 0094763650397 or 94773596258 how can i incorporate this scenario.

Comment: check the above comment

Comment: i have a small concern, ^(00)?947[76]\d{7}$ in this pattern i need to change it to this scenario whereas 94 is also optional but if 00 is being sent then 94 should be mandatory, is it possible for me to incorporate this  scenario to this pattern. so far i changed the pattern to ^(00)?(94)?7[76]\d{7}$ but im unable to make the 94 mandatory if 00 is entered.

Comment: @isham, if i understand you correctly: `^(0094|(94)?)7[76]\d{7}$`

Comment: im getting this error when i add the + , could you tell me what am i doing wrong in here. parsing "^(0094|(+94)?)7[76]\d{7}$" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.

Comment: @Isham, you need to read about regular expressions :) use `\+`